# Can the lack of credit based coursework be compensated by published works for faculty applications?

Tags: publications, application, faculty-application, coursework

Due to lack of foresight, I did not take any graduate level advanced mathematics or numerical analysis course. Nor do I have good grades on the subjects during my undergraduate studies.

However, I have 3 publications in Q1 interdisciplinary journals (not mathematical or numerical analysis journals) which required the application of the mathematical and numerical analysis concepts. Though, I mostly used commercial software in my research, I self studied, relearned all the required fundamentals from different sources (books, online courses, documentations).

Can the lack of credit based graduate coursework be a huge bottleneck in my future faculty applications? Can it be compensated by published works?

Is there something I can do in the next 1-1.5 years (before I start applying to places), that can put me in a better position?

Comment: I've never seen a faculty application ever ask for grades or transcripts

Comment: You don't say whether you actually earned a doctorate.

Comment: @Buffy yes, I did earn my PhD recently, and am pursuing a postdoc.

Comment: Then your grades and coursework is pretty much irrelevant. For some teaching jobs people might want to know about your qualifications to teach, say, undergraduates.

Answer (score 1):

> Can the lack of credit based graduate coursework be a huge bottleneck in my future faculty applications? Can it be compensated by published works?

I am not sure about positions at a SLAC or for a more teaching-oriented position, but for your run-off-the-mill tenure-track at a research university nobody will care in the first place what courses you took, or which grades you got. And if the department indeed thinks that specific knowledge is crucial to your position (e.g., because of teaching needs), I would expect that you can at least make a convincing case during the interviews that your published research demonstrates your mastery in this field.

So I would not say that anything related to graduate coursework can *ever* be a "huge bottleneck" for the kinds of positions that I am familiar with, and even if a specific position requires knowledge that is not visible from your transcript your published research should be a rather convincing argument.

Also, just to echo mmeent's comment:

> "I've never seen a faculty application ever ask for grades or transcripts."

Me neither, and I have applied to north of 50 positions on 3 continents.

Comment: In my experience 20% of positions request transcripts.

Answer (score 0):

At certain American institutions, and especially community colleges, you will need a certain number of credit-hours of graduate course work in a certain field to get a job.  Probably no exceptions are permitted.

Other institutions will not care at all.